# Getting Null Pointer Exception in sqoop

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I am executing a sqoop command to get a table from mysql to Hive.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://999.999.999.999:3307/dbname
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username 'abc' --password 'abc' 
--table 'surv_regression' --create-hive-table --hive-table 'surv_reg3
--hive-import --bindir ./ --m 1
```

The error that i am getting is

```
ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Could you add the `--verbose` option to the sqoop command and show the complete exception message?